# Codeigniter ActiveRecord not returning any results for particular tableUn

Tags: database, codeigniter, activerecord

Having a problem with returning results from one particular table in a database.

I have two tables:

```
a) repository_notes
b) repository_noteupdates (this one is giving the problem)
```

Here is an image showing there are some data in both tables using a simple select * query using Navicat.

[image]
[http://imgur.com/GA6bn](https://imgur.com/GA6bn)

However When I query repository_notes below:

```
print_r($this->db->get('repository_notes')->result_array());
```

It gives me the following result set:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [note_id] => 1
        [note_title] => This is my note
        [note_content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In laoreet lobortis lacus, ac iaculis risus tristique nec. Curabitur porta gravida est, non tincidunt nunc porta nec. Nunc diam metus, feugiat non lobortis
        [note_userId] => 2302
        [note_pageno] => 12
        [note_deleted] => 0
        [note_bookid] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [note_id] => 2
        [note_title] => This is my note
        [note_content] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In laoreet lobortis lacus, ac iaculis risus tristique nec. Curabitur porta gravida est, non tincidunt nunc porta nec. Nunc diam metus, feugiat non lobortis
        [note_userId] => 2302
        [note_pageno] => 12
        [note_deleted] => 0
        [note_bookid] => 12
    )
```

However when I run the query below:

print_r($this->db->get('repository_noteupdates')->result_array());

I get no results:

```
 Array
    (
    )
```

Have any of you seen anything like this before and have a solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like
    `$sql = "SELECT * FROM repository_noteupdates";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    print_r($query->result_array());`

Comment: I have just tried that and it did not work. However If i cahnge to     `$sql = "SELECT * FROM repository_notes"; $query = $this->db->query($sql); print_r($query->result_array());` it does work for the other table. @WillSampson

Comment: try print_r($this->db->last_query()); and see what is actually being queried after your query.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the database and not codeigniter, i would make sure your tables are set up correctly and are both accessible from the settings you placed in your database config file.

Comment: It seems to be performing the correct query
`SELECT * FROM repository_noteupdates`
after running
`print_r($this->db->last_query());` @JohnB

Comment: @WillSampson - both tables were setup at the same time using navicat and are in the same database. Are there any suggestions on what settings might have affected this table? I agree that it is probably not codeigniter that is causing the issue, but i have no idea how to troubleshoot this on a database level.

Comment: and your config file isn't set up to use a prefix, right?

Comment: @JohnB - Right - `$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';`

Comment: try turning the profiler on and see if it shows you any weird stuff.

Comment: Right, so I found the solution for this. It seems that if i remove the name `update` from the table name, it seems to work. So i have called the table `repository_noteupdata` and it is now working. Thanks guys for helping out. It is strange because I cannot find any documentation saying `update` is a reserved word for a table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution for this.

It seems that if i remove the name update from the table name, it seems to work. So i have called the table `repository_noteupdata` instead of `repository_noteupdates`
and it is now working.

Thanks guys for helping out. It is strange because I cannot find any documentation in codeigniter saying update is a reserved word for a table name.

Comment: It should not be, i have a suspicion it was something else but who knows.  Very strange that this change fixed it for you.